# Combining multiple bar type load cells to measure large weights

Tags: arduino-uno

This is my first post here. I want to make a scale that can measure weights up to 60kg. I have three 20kg bar type load cells. I can successfully measure weights with the load cells individually (just up to 20kg of course). Is there a way I can combine the three load cells and aggregate the measurements from each of them so as to get a maximum measurement of 60kg (hysteresis taken into consideration too). Also, what is the optimal way to arrange the load cells so that the weight to be measured will be evenly distributed across the three load cells? I will really appreciate your inputs.

Comment: How are you going to connect them mechanically? How will they behave when connected in such a fashion? Simply get a cell rated for 60Kg or more.

Answer (score 1):

In the world of scales multiple load cells are simply parallel wired together. The combined output voltage is very, very accurate. This is the way nearly all multi-load cell scales work.